# Sudoku Backtracking Algorithm Solver raising a RecursionError

Tags: python, sudoku, recursive-backtracking

I'm creating a text based Sudoku solver and everytime I run the code I hit a RecursionError error. I thought something was wrong with my code so I increased the recursion depth and it works fine, I'm just not sure how to rewrite my function so that I can get rid of the recursion depth error.

```
def backtrack (self):
    '''Goes back in the grid and checks for valid numbers'''
    del self.history[len(self.history) - 1]  # goes back to the last spot, not current
    self.pos = self.history[len(self.history) - 1]  # reassign current position
    for numbers in range(9):
        if self.valid(numbers + 1) and (numbers + 1) != self.board[self.pos[0]][self.pos[1]]:  # valid number but not the same as before
            self.board[self.pos[0]][self.pos[1]] = numbers + 1
            return True
    self.board[self.pos[0]][self.pos[1]] = 0 #reset this position to 0
    return False


def solve(self): #recursive, once you get to the end of the board it's solved
    '''solves the Sudoku board, backtrack alg'''
    empty = self.find_empty()
    if not empty:
        return None
    if empty: #if there's an empty spot on the grid:
        for nums in range(9): #try all numbers on a specific spot
            if self.valid(nums+1): #theres no numbers on the column, row, or grid
                self.board[self.pos[0]][self.pos[1]] = nums+1
                break

            elif nums == 8: #reached end of for loop, no number fits in the grid
                while self.backtrack() == False: #keep going until we can plug in a number
                    if self.backtrack() == True:
                        break
        self.solve()  #recursive process

board = Sudoku([
    [7, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
    [6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 9],
    [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 7, 8],
    [0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 2, 6, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 9, 3, 0],
    [9, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5],
    [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0],
    [0, 4, 9, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7]
        ])
board.solve()
```

For clarification, self.history is a list of tuples which remembers all the 0s we've iterated through and self.pos is the current grid we want to check. I increased the recursion limit and it solves a little more than half the board vs. just half the board as before but I have 0 idea how to rewrite the recursive part. I know it's a bit much but help is appreciated!

```
Error Log:
File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Sudoku/sudoko_alg.py", line 26, in on_column
    for i in range (9):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that every time a change is made to the board in `self.solve()`, a new call to self.solve() is issued. `self.solve()` never returns a value to the parent `self.solve()` call, so none of the functions calls ever exit until the very end of the code.

I believe what you intended to do is make it so that each time a value is added, a new call to `self.solve()` is made. And each time a value is discovered to be invalid, some indicator (i.e. `False`) is returned to the previous call of `self.solve()`. In this implementation, there would be at most 81 recursive calls to `self.solve()`. In your current architecture, there could be as many as 9^81 recursive calls, hence the `RecursionError` as you quickly use up available space in the stack with each successive call.

To fix, I suggest modifying your code so that `self.solve()` returns `True` if there is a valid board combination and `False` otherwise, and make a recursive call to `self.solve()` every time a value is added. Based on this approach I think you need only one function (solve) and don't need a backtrack function.

Pseudocode:

```
def self.solve():
    # find the next unassigned square
    # for each value in range (1,9) assign that value to square and make recursive call to solve()
    # if all recursive calls return False, return False
    # if any call to solve() ever returns True, a valid solution to the board has been found
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reformulating your algorithm as an iteration.

```
# Verty rough sketch!
states = [Sudoku(initial_numbers)] #a list with the starting configuration
for state in iter(states):
    if state.is_solved():
        print("success!")
        break
    states += state.get_next_states()
```